# How can I find the norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let  $v $ be a $2\times 2$ matrix as follow:
$$v=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &   \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}\\
  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} &  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
\end{pmatrix} $$
then $\|v\|^2=(v,v).$ What does that mean? The left hand side is a scalar, so the right hand must be the scalar too.

What is the definition of $(v,v)$. Should I multiply $v$ and $v$ element by element, then add them together, or like multipling of two matrices, first find $v^2$ then add them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $(\cdot,\cdot)$ refers to an inner product on the space of matrices, such as the [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product). Any choice of inner product then induces a norm $\|\cdot\| = \sqrt{(\cdot,\cdot)}$.